# Multi Channel Hyperledger Fabric - How peer works

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Assume we have one `peer0` who is subscribed to `Channel1` and `Channel2`. When a transaction needs to be committed that needs to be shared in both the channels from client app i.e `Nodejs`, should this be sent to both channels manually or does it synchronize the ledger data in other channels based on peer subscription to channels when I send it to one channel?

Answer (score 0):

Synchronize of the ledgers will not be possible as it belongs to separate channels. You might have to sync it Manually.

Comment: [Comments posted as an answer are subject to removal.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)